# How to use jquery to create progress bar for loading an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, capacity

I want to take size in bytes of image in page at the first load page, and then create a loading bar and show it loading similar preloader of flash. But I don't know if jQuery can take size in bytes of image or not.

Comment: @Robert Good guess, I'd say, but who knows...? :) There's one more instance of "capacity" in the question BTW.

Comment: @deceze: (S)He wants a progress bar for the initially-loading image.

Comment: oh.. sorry..  i want to take size(mb) of image, not size(width-height) of image.. by Jquery

Thankyou for edit my question ^^. i'm talking Eng very bad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you determine the file size in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126905/how-can-you-determine-the-file-size-in-javascript)

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF [How can you determine the file size in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126905/how-can-you-determine-the-file-size-in-javascript.) Read the two questions again.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of these answers require something server-side to determine the file-size (please correct me if I'm wrong), but it would probably be best to preload the size from server-size or do an AJAX request to determine the file-size, but the latter seems counter productive.

Comment: Wouldn't be hard to put it in a manifest-style entry that had the image sizes. Not quite sure how you'd do a preloader style thing though. Finding the status of the downloading image is the hard part.