# How to validate file size before uploading?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you determine the file size in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126905/how-can-you-determine-the-file-size-in-javascript)

GMail has the option to check file size and alerting without letting the page posting back.

How can I implement this feature myself?

Answer (score 5):

Using HTML5, you can achieve this on the client side using JavaScript. This is jQuery but it works without as well of course: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/S4mEv/2/. Note that it's not available in all browsers (yet).

```
$('#file').change(function() {
    alert(this.files[0].size + " bytes");
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), it's a jQuery plugin that uses flash for checking file size and has other neat functions.
http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/sizelimit/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that file HTML5 JS File API

You can test run the below codes in my web IDE (but please use google chrome or FF):
http://codesocialist.com/#/?s=bN

The below codes retrieve the filetype and filesize for you :)

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

// Check for the various File API support.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {

    // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
          output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ', f.size, ' bytes </strong></li>');
        }

        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    }

    // Bind Event Listener
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

} else {
    alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

Comment: If the questions are duplicates, please flag them as such. Please do not copy and paste your answer from one to another. Copy and Pasting in programming is bad, why would it be good for an answer on programming?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail uses a Flash application for this purpose.  If you want to check file sizes, you need to do this from within such an environment; JavaScript alone has no mechanism to accomplish this.

Comment: In combination with HTML5 it does. When the user selects a file in a `<input type=file>`, you can use the `onchange` event and look for the file selected. Also includes file size. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File

Comment: Interesting, good to know.  You might consider adding that as an alternate answer.

Comment: Once see the hotmail site. the total site developed by .net,In that site when upload a file display the caution same like that i want dude.