# Can Javascript be used to test the size of a file to be uploaded?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you determine the file size in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126905/how-can-you-determine-the-file-size-in-javascript)
>   [How to validate file size before uploading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146816/how-to-validate-file-size-before-uploading)

Does Javascript support a function that posts alert if file which is supposed to be uploaded is bigger than a limit?

Comment: This *is not a duplicate* (at least of question 1126905)! The "possible duplicate" is asking about the size of a file *located at a url*, where this is asking about the size of a file *in a `<input type='file'>` field*.

Comment: @DavidWolever this is a duplicate, but not 1126905.